# Issues getting access to bound jar attributes in Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, jar, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use Calendar from https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView in my Xamarin Android app.
I have built a.jar library and added it to project as it is described in tutorial. Everything works fine except that I can't get access to internal jar attributes e.g. TextSize, TextColor etc. 
After adding zip with res/attr.xml (found that solution on xamarin forums) to binding library and rebuild solution attributes appeared in Resources file and I can access them in properties of Calendar control. The problem is that changing them does nothing at all although there are no building exceptions.
Can you give me advice what is wrong here?

Link to zip with my project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywEimiS61KKTzB6Ti1aT1dnSjQ

There is a screenshot from emulator with shown control properties and xml:
[image]